# Why does plymouth fail consistently after booting into second OS?

Tags: gentoo, uefi, bootsplash

I have dual-boot UEFI (non-secure) Gentoo and Fedora.  After I build my kernel for Gentoo, plymouth bootsplash works perfectly every time.

If I boot into boot option 2, Fedora, even once - plymouth never loads when I boot back into Gentoo later.  I can see the plymouth service scroll by in the verbose textual boot.

If I rebuild the kernel, even without changing options, plymouth service is restored to Gentoo.  **Is there a way to keep plymouth working without reinstalling the kernel everyday?**

**Gentoo** boots with efi, initramfs for use with luks partitions. ([Sakaki install tutorial](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Sakaki's_EFI_Install_Guide))
**Fedora 24** has its efi selection point to the standard grub2 bootloader (default desktop install)

After boot, I don't see any failed processes on systemd:

```
ruby ~ # systemctl --failed
0 loaded units listed. Pass --all to see loaded but inactive units, too.
To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
```

Comment: Are you using GRUB?

Comment: @fpmurphy1 Not for Gentoo (details added to original post).

Comment: OK, you are EFISTUB booting Gentoo.   Suggest you also EFISTUB boot Fedora24. Then you will not need GRUB

Comment: @fpmurphy1 If I don't have the Gentoo boot key inserted, the EFISTUB points to Fedora's GRUB entry.  So Fedora uses EFI and GRUB2 - which is weird, but is how Fedora installs by default.  That's not my concern. I'm interested in keeping the plymouth boot screen and I have no idea why it malfunctions if I boot the Fedora EFI entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in my question, I am using an EFI boot with systemd in Sakaki's tutorial.  Regardless of the options that I had set for plymouth during `buildkernel --easy-setup`, I was apparently experiencing the [versionitis](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Sakaki%27s_EFI_Install_Guide/Configuring_systemd_and_Installing_Necessary_Tools#Enabling_plymouth.2C_Rebuilding_the_Kernel.2C_and_Restarting_.28Optional_Step.29) as mentioned in his tutorial:

> If you do change the bootfile location to /EFI/Boot/gentoo.efi below,
>   please note that by default you will still have your prior kernel
>   present on the boot USB key, with the path /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi.
>   Since this can cause 'versionitis' issues in the future (for example,
>   if your BIOS attempts to boot it, because the EFI boot order has
>   become corrupted for some reason), feel free to delete the older
>   /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi file from the USB key, once you have verified
>   that the new /EFI/Boot/gentoo.efi variant works.

Apparently, my Toshiba Satellite was resetting the efi boot order back to `boox64.efi` every time that I booted into my alternate OS.

**The fix**: I had to

1. Remove the old boot entry from my USB key `mv -v /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi -t ~/Downloads`
2. Manually fix the boot entry from my other OS (my EFI boot USB as /dev/sdb) with `efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sdb -p 1 -L "Gentoo" -l "\EFI\Boot\gentoo.efi"`
3. Remove the incorrect boot entry, in my case just appearing as *linux* with instructions from https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Efibootmgr
4. Lastly, reorder the boot entry ([ibid](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Efibootmgr)) so that *Gentoo USB* was 1st, 2nd *Other Linux*, 3rd *EFI USB*, 4th *EFI Network*.